# How can I restore files in Jupyter?

Tags: python, ipython, backup, jupyter, restore

I had a Python version 3.6.5 and I deleted whole Python with my Jupyter installed. Than I installed Python 3.7.0, but it does not support some modules now, so I deleted that and again installed Python 3.6.6 but now I don't have my Jupyter files there. Do you know how can I restore my old files?

Comment: You mean Jupyter installation files?

Comment: I mean Jupyter notebooks - the files at server, where I had my Python code

Comment: If you unistall Python or Jupyter Notebook,the codes you created won't be deleted.

Comment: Yes, it is - at least I think - when I launch server via "jupyter notebook" command I don't have any python files there

Comment: Are you sure you are launching at the same directory where you stored the files before?

Comment: I also deleted whole directory with python - then I make new and I have installed Python 3.6.6 there. It was clear python, then I installed Jupyter

Comment: So you deleted your codes and notebooks(.ipynb files) as well?

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819322/how-to-recover-deleted-ipython-notebooks

Comment: I think - yes, because I deleted "Python36" folder, where I have everything - is there any way, how to restore that?

Comment: Was that link  helpful?

Comment: I don't know how to do it  - I am using Windows and I don't understand this part ~/.ipython_checkpoints/