# How to restore a deleted Jupyter notebook file

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I accidentally deleted a jupyter notebook file on my Google Cloud instance. I wonder if there's anyway to restore/recover the file?

Comment: how did you delete it? with `rm` ?

Comment: @TravisWebb No, I had the jupyter notebook browser open, instead of shutting down my notebook I pressed the removing button. My jupyter notebook files are on my Google Cloud instance (I'm running jupyter on GC server), you're suggesting that it does not have anything to do with Google Cloud?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819322/how-to-recover-deleted-ipython-notebooks

Comment: You can try using [`extundelete`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/extundelete.1.html) but there are no guarantees. I don't think this has much to do with Google, seems like a Jupyter-specific issue.

Comment: @ahmed.soli had already tried every solution there, did not work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [this link](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3631), I found the solution. Files deleted in the browser should probably be in a **Trash** folder. In my case and on my Google Cloud instance, the deleted files were in the following path.

```
cd ~/.local/share/Trash/files/
```

By using `ls`, list the files and see if your file is in this folder. If yes, then simply using the `mv` command you can move your deleted file to the path you want.

Comment: move cmd: `mv [source] [destination]`