# How to recover a jupyter notebook from firefox browser cache?

Tags: python, firefox, caching, jupyter-notebook

I was working on a jupyter notebook on my firefox browser. I no longer have access to the notebook (It was accidentally removed from the server).

I am looking for ways to recover my codes from the browser cache. Here are the things I have already done:

- I have been through [this post's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819322/how-to-recover-deleted-ipython-notebooks) answers (@Vivek-Ananth and @Thuener) that are most similar to my situation. But the answers were given a couple of years ago and cache in firefox is now stored differently.
  I found the directory that cache is being stored in `about:cache`.
  But the files are encrypted and I cannot use `grep` to find the file I'm looking for from them.
- I went to memory and disk `List Cache Entries` that are listed in `about:cache`'s page in firefox and tried to find the notebook from the list. The notebook is in the list but when I click on it, the information does not include my codes (sometimes it contains some java codes!)

I am wondering if there is any way to find a jupyter notebook's content with browser cache?