# Cannot find .ipynb in directory that says it was last modified recently but has no recently modified files

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, storage

Hi so I have been working on a notebook the last few days and showed it to my advisor yesterday and we walked through it together. I tried to start working on the project this morning and cannot find the file that I was working on. What is strange is that the directory that I was working in says it was last modified yesterday but when I look through the directory the file I am looking for cannot be found. I know that you are probably thinking "this ding deleted the file on accident" and although I really dont know how that could have happened, that is one suspicion of mine, but when looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819322/how-to-recover-deleted-ipython-notebooks they mention that it should go to trash for my version of jupyter notebook upon deletion.

I am asking if there is any way to possibly get the file back? or anywhere I can look for the file? I have looked in my trash can but it is not there.

MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3
Jupyter NoteBook 6.1.5
Conda Version: 4.9.2
Conda-build version: 3.20.5
Python: 3.8.5.final.0

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why this was the case but here is:

I could not find the file of interest. Did all methods from before in above link, once I looked in the icloud Desktop in my finder it suddenly appeared in the normal desktop directory. Idk why, but if this happens to you, check the icloud directory corresponding to the directory you are in and it may appear in the corresponding normal directory after. Lesson learned: do some version control.