# Deleted files from Jupyter Notebook, how can I restore

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook

I was doing work in Jupyter Notebook for the first time in a while and deleted a good amount of files, forgetting that they were directly linked to my local files. Completely messed up my ability to run Python and Jupyter Notebook and a few more applications. Does anyone know a way to reset the deletions(don't have Time Machine set up). Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover deleted iPython Notebooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38819322/how-to-recover-deleted-ipython-notebooks)

Comment: @ARK1375 it did partially, I unfortunately moved all the files to a dummy folder on my desktop to make sure I didn't accidentally delete. Just discovered the "put back" feature afterwards unfortunately.