# How can I recover a JupyterLite file after a computer reset?

Tags: jupyter, ipynb

I worked on a project I need to submit. Jupyter wasn't working on my computer so I worked with a JupyterLite notebook. Looks like my computer reset while I was taking a break, and when I turned the screen on I had to log back in as a user into my chrome page. When I opened to JupyterLite again there is no sign of the workbook and it is just the blank intro page. I don't know how to use the terminal to try and find it or if it is even exists anywhere, can't find help in Anaconda support and forum.I didn't delete anything myself, I got logged out of the computer. [I don't know how to try this in the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371284/recover-deleted-ipython-jupyter-notebook)

Trying to find the notebook I was working on

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72062489/where-is-jupyterlite-notebook-located-locally-on-windows/72063769#comment127332294_72063769) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/files-in-jupyterlite-all-disappeared/17785/2?u=fomightez). Save to your local regular drive regularly and often when working. You can think of the virtual system running deep inside your browser as a 'remote' system because you cannot access it directly. So you'll want to save to your normal drive. About looking for support from Anaconda? As far as I know, they don't distribute JupyterLite.

Comment: **Practical summary**: As long as your browser didn't reset the browser cache and stuff **usually** if you go back to the very same site **in the very same browser** where you had worked with JupyterLite, the notebooks are usually there in the file navigation panel. Avoid clearing your browser if planning to work with JupyterLite. Also don't work incognito. Although using an incognito window is a nice trick for getting a **temporary** clean environment.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected so, and I think the reset happened because of privacy settings on my computer. I was surprised that when you work in jupyterlyte online, the default setting is not on autosave and you need to manually check it, which I just found. I personally didn't delete the notebook or clear the browsing history, so I am still trying to go back to the same browser on chrome but maybe I'm missing something because it doesn't show anything from before.

Comment: Sorry that this has happened to you. I changed your title to fix the spelling so that hopefully it may help others in the future.

Comment: I appreciate your effort Wayne. I've worked on this issue several hours but it's gone, my conclusion is that my privacy settings made me become anonymous to the website, and start over from blank. Of course, either way it would just be temporarily online no matter what happens. So, to avoid it, click "file-save notebook" frequently. Better yet, I shouldn't have used it at all.

Comment: I need to point out that, " temporarily online no matter what happens" isn't correct. Normally with typical user settings on a computer JupyterLite isn't temporary. I've got notebooks going back months that show up in my navigation panel presently when I open JupyterLite from the main site the typical way. I can usually only get a 'clean' session by using Incognito mode. But my computer is set up as a typical single user computer, leaving privacy settings so I can use my computer without having to login everywhere. And a notebook made in JupyterLite isn't online ever, only in your browser.